# Large scale sparse system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the best know algorithm for solving a large sparse system of linear equations? The system I'm working on is not symmetric, not positive definite and integer. The only benefit is being sparse. I also need to point out that the matrix is not square. The dimension is $m\times n$ and it is not generally either underestimate or overestimate.

Comment: This question is under defined: the "best method" depends on the sparsity structure...

Comment: I suggest asking on scicomp.stackexchange.com.  But you'll want to clarify the question.

Comment: In general, so-called "black-box" linear algebra techniques offer very good theoretical and practical performance for sparse or structured matrix operations. The basic idea is to treat matrix multiplication as an oracle: in the sparse or structured case, this will have subquadratic complexity and can be leveraged to accelerate more complex operations.